# Configuring a vncserver so it's only accessible from my ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, firewall, vnc

Since I use vnc through an ssh tunnel, is there any way I can block the open vnc port that the remote machine is listening on without it affecting my ability to use the ssh tunnel?  Both machines are linux debian based.

Answer (score 7):

I use `vncserver -localhost [other options here]` when I start the `vncserver` on my debian boxes.  This means VNC only accepts connections from the loopback of the remote machine.

Comment: @Christopher, you're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the VNC server to only accept connections from your IP.